# there is no module named keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm using anaconda3 and vscode

I am trying to import *Sequential* from tensorflow.keras.models but keras can't be found.
I installed tensorflow by pip

and also when I run it, an error like this comes out.
"Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found"
could it be because I am doing this on a laptop with no GPU?

I am new to tensorflow so I'm sorry if it makes no sense.

Comment: How are you importing Sequential?

Comment: make sure about your virtual environments. base is the default V.E for conda

Comment: I am importing Sequential with  from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

Answer (score 0):

You can get past this error by doing os.add_dll_directory("C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.2/bin") before importing tensorflow.
Gpu is not mandatory its upto you,You have either not installed CUDA correctly (and also cudnn) or you have installed the wrong version, for the TF binary you are trying to use.
Install : pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.6 or 2.7 please try to re install and let us know.

please refer to similar issues: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53060)[link1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48868) [link2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows) [link3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43193)